# Android retain selected item from listfragment on screen change (landscape)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm new to Fragments and am playing around with it. Basically I want a master/detail layout. My master pane is the songs list and the detail is each song's lyrics.

So this is what I have:

**MainActivity.class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TitlesFragment.OnItemSelectListener{

// Whether or not we are in dual-pane mode
boolean mIsDualPane = false;

int mArtIndex = 0;

TitlesFragment mTitleFragment;
DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitleFragment = (TitlesFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.titlesFragment);

    descriptionFragment = 
            (DescriptionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.descriptionFragment);

    View descriptionView = findViewById(R.id.descriptionFragment);
    mIsDualPane = descriptionView != null && descriptionView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    Log.e("", "" + mIsDualPane);


    mTitleFragment.setSelection(0);
    if(mIsDualPane) {
        String description = Songs.lyrics[mArtIndex].toString();
        descriptionFragment.setDescriptionIntoFragment(description);
    }
    restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

/*
 * Implements the interface declared into TitlesFragment class
 * If the screen is in portrait mode launch a second activity instead of 
 * showing the text into the second fragment (as the second fragment is not visible)
 */
@Override
public void onItemSelect(int index) {
    String description = Songs.lyrics[index].toString();
    if(descriptionFragment != null && descriptionFragment.isInLayout())
    {
        descriptionFragment.setDescriptionIntoFragment(description);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lyrics", description);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

/** Restore category/article selection from saved state. */
void restoreSelection(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (mIsDualPane) {

            int artIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("artIndex", 0);
            String description = Songs.lyrics[artIndex].toString();
            mTitleFragment.setSelection(artIndex);
            descriptionFragment.setDescriptionIntoFragment(description);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);
}

/** Save instance state. Saves current category/article index. */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("artIndex", mArtIndex);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**TitlesFragment.class:**

```
public class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {

private OnItemSelectListener itemSelectListener;

//public interface used to communicate with activities
public interface OnItemSelectListener
{
    public void onItemSelect(int index);
}

//Check if the parent activity has implemented the public interface
//if not, throw an exception
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        itemSelectListener = (OnItemSelectListener) activity;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnItemSelectListener");
    }
}


//launch the method described into the interface when the user click on an item
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    itemSelectListener.onItemSelect(position);
}


@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    int layout = 0;
    /*
     * Pick a different layout for the list item based on the sdk version,
     * as the simple_list_item_activated_1 is not compatible on devices
     * running sdk < 11 and could throw a fatal exception
     */
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    }
        else layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Songs.titles);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**DescriptionActivity.class:**

```
public class DescriptionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    else setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras != null)
    {
        String lyrics = extras.getString("lyrics");
        DescriptionFragment descriptionFragment = 
                (DescriptionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.descriptionFragment);
        if(descriptionFragment != null && descriptionFragment.isInLayout())
        {
            descriptionFragment.setDescriptionIntoFragment(lyrics);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I selected the 3rd item from the listview on portrait mode and changed to landscape mode, the detail is incorrect, it selected the first (0) detail. What seems to be wrong with my code? Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: When the orientation changed to "landscape", is there any process (e.g. loading or saving something) that you would like to do? If there isn't any, then I think I have a good answer for you.

Comment: Yes I am saving the index

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand where you have `setDescriptionIntoFragment` function? Why didn't you save and restore in fragment with `onSaveInstanceState` and `restoreSelection`?

I think that your position equals 0 because when you call `setSelection` you have no data in your fragment's adapter and views are not created.

Answer (score -1):

If all you need is to make the screen orientation change to **landscape**, then simply open your **manifest.xml**, look for the activity you would like to change its orientation, add `android:configChanges` just like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
</activity>
```

Comment: The master/detail flow is all about handling both landscape and portrait in the appropriate manner, so you answer completely misses the point.